# Learning Golang using gopacket as a starter

Tags: go, dns, gopacket

I have started to learn golang recently (January). I am trying to reproduce a tool we have internally that is written in Python in Go.

So I have the tool working completely for UDP decoding of DNS, however I have been struggling for a week trying to get TCP based DNS decoding. My objective is to log DNS source, destination, query and answers for every packet that hits our DNS servers. In a similar way to what [dnstap](http://dnstap.info/) does, however we have an internal solution currently using Python to suit our in-house custom logging and event correlation system.

```
    func Listen(h *pcap.Handle, c *Config, logger chan<- *dnslog) {
        qType := decodeQuery()
        OpCode := decodeOpCode()
        parser := gopacket.NewDecodingLayerParser(
            layers.LayerTypeEthernet,
            &eth,
            &ip4,
            &ip6,
            &tcp,
            &udp,
            &dns,
            )

            decoded := make([]gopacket.LayerType, 0, 10)

        for {
            data, _, err := h.ZeroCopyReadPacketData()
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("Error reading packet data ", err)
                continue
            }

            dnslog := &dnslog{}

            err = parser.DecodeLayers(data, &decoded)
            for _, layer := range decoded {
                switch layer {
                case layers.LayerTypeIPv4:
                    dnslog.Dst = ip4.DstIP.String()
                    dnslog.Src = ip4.SrcIP.String()
                case layers.LayerTypeIPv6:
                    dnslog.Dst = ip6.DstIP.String()
                    dnslog.Src = ip6.SrcIP.String()
                case layers.LayerTypeTCP:
                    dnslog.Srcport = fmt.Sprintf("%d", tcp.SrcPort)
                    dnslog.Dstport = fmt.Sprintf("%d", tcp.DstPort)
                case layers.LayerTypeUDP:
                    dnslog.Srcport = fmt.Sprintf("%d", udp.SrcPort)
                    dnslog.Dstport = fmt.Sprintf("%d", udp.DstPort)
                case layers.LayerTypeDNS:
                    dnslog.Truncated = dns.TC
                    for _, q := range dns.Questions {
                        dnslog.OpCode = OpCode[uint8(dns.OpCode)]
                        dnslog.QueryCount = dns.QDCount
                        dnslog.AnswerCount = dns.ANCount
                        }
                    }
            }
        logger <- dnslog
    }
```

I have attempted to force the NextLayerType in layers/tcp.go to the DNS Layertype etc in an attempt to find what I am missing. So far no luck. Any advice would be ace. What we see with UDP is the following output. (pprint json encoded output)

`[{
    "src": "172.10.56.23",
    "src_port": "52464",
    "dst": "172.10.16.120",
    "dst_port": "53",
    "bytes": 63,
    "transport": "UDP",
    "reply_code": "Query",
    "query_count": 1,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "question": ["helposx.apple.com"],
    "query_type": "A",
    "answer": null,
    "truncated": false
}, {
    "src": "172.10.16.120",
    "src_port": "53",
    "dst": "172.10.56.23",
    "dst_port": "52464",
    "bytes": 156,
    "transport": "UDP",
    "reply_code": "Query",
    "query_count": 1,
    "answer_count": 3,
    "question": ["helposx.apple.com"],
    "query_type": "A",
    "answer": [{
        "response-name": "helposx.apple.com",
        "response-query_type": "CNAME",
        "response-ttl": 4607,
        "response-bytes": 31,
        "response-cname": "helposx.apple.com.edgekey.net",
        "response-soa": {},
        "response-srv": {},
        "response-mx": {}
    }, {
        "response-name": "helposx.apple.com.edgekey.net",
        "response-query_type": "CNAME",
        "response-ttl": 33,
        "response-bytes": 22,
        "response-cname": "e3167.e9.akamaiedge.net",
        "response-soa": {},
        "response-srv": {},
        "response-mx": {}
    }, {
        "response-name": "e3167.e9.akamaiedge.net",
        "response-query_type": "A",
        "response-ttl": 13,
        "response-bytes": 4,
        "response-ip": "104.98.20.77",
        "response-soa": {},
        "response-srv": {},
        "response-mx": {}
    }],
    "truncated": false
}]`

If I now do exactly the same query using dig +tcp (forces TCP) I get the following output.

`[{
    "src": "172.10.56.23",
    "src_port": "57188",
    "dst": "172.10.16.120",
    "dst_port": "53",
    "bytes": 64,
    "transport": "TCP",
    "reply_code": "",
    "query_count": 0,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "question": null,
    "query_type": "",
    "answer": null,
    "truncated": false
}, {
    "src": "172.10.16.120",
    "src_port": "53",
    "dst": "172.10.56.23",
    "dst_port": "57188",
    "bytes": 60,
    "transport": "TCP",
    "reply_code": "",
    "query_count": 0,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "question": null,
    "query_type": "",
    "answer": null,
    "truncated": false
}, {
    "src": "172.10.56.23",
    "src_port": "57188",
    "dst": "172.10.16.120",
    "dst_port": "53",
    "bytes": 52,
    "transport": "TCP",
    "reply_code": "",
    "query_count": 0,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "question": null,
    "query_type": "",
    "answer": null,
    "truncated": false
}, {
    "src": "172.10.56.23",
    "src_port": "57188",
    "dst": "172.10.16.120",
    "dst_port": "53",
    "bytes": 86,
    "transport": "TCP",
    "reply_code": "",
    "query_count": 0,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "question": null,
    "query_type": "",
    "answer": null,
    "truncated": false
}, {
    "src": "172.10.16.120",
    "src_port": "53",
    "dst": "172.10.56.23",
    "dst_port": "57188",
    "bytes": 102,
    "transport": "TCP",
    "reply_code": "",
    "query_count": 0,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "question": null,
    "query_type": "",
    "answer": null,
    "truncated": false
}, {
    "src": "172.10.56.23",
    "src_port": "57188",
    "dst": "172.10.16.120",
    "dst_port": "53",
    "bytes": 52,
    "transport": "TCP",
    "reply_code": "",
    "query_count": 0,
    "answer_count": 0,
    "question": null,
    "query_type": "",
    "answer": null,
    "truncated": false
}]`

From looking at the same packets in wireshark I can see that those various packets are the TCP handshake, then a response. Which is not decoded.

When I add in a fmt.Println(layer) after the for _, layer := range decoded line I get the following.

Ethernet
IPv4
TCP
<< JSON OUTPUT ABOVE.

VS

Ethernet
IPv4
UDP
DNS

As you can see there is never a next decoder for the TCP based DNS. It just stops at TCP. I am unsure as to what the solution is. Reading the upstream library looks like it should work. However it does not and I am confused to where I should be looking. Being new to Go it is sending me in loops.

Comment: Difficult/impossible to answer without more data.  Suggest making and posting a _brief_ example (as small as possible) that demonstrates your exact problem - including what data you expect to show up at what point (e.g. some fmt.Printf("THIS SHOULD BE X BUT PRINTS Y: %..."); as well as how you are getting the input to the program - just from a "dig" or what? Provide the exact command line.)  Please also read this if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? And ... is your solution opensource by any chance? I need to solve a very similar problem and I would love to reuse your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I [requested support for support for DNS over TCP](https://github.com/google/gopacket/issues/236) but ended up [implementing it myself in the end](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope/blob/45a9367d97db5fd4cdd6e79ff55819718dcc7456/probe/endpoint/dns_snooper_linux_amd64.go#L115-L167).

It doesn't yet support fragmentation of TCP segments, but it's good enough for my usecase (for now).